# Get file name from complex URI

Tags: java, android, url, download, filenames

I want to download a file which does not end with file name and extension.

For example below mentioned uri is for downloading a file. What will be the best way to get the name of the file (including its extension) to save it after downloading.

> https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/20/32/mushroom-967719_640.jpg?attachment

The following code is returning "mushroom-967719_640.jpg?attachment"

```
URL url = new URL(FILE_URI);
...........................
File downloadingFile = new File(url.getFile());
downloadingFile.getName();
```

I am looking for  general solution where I can get the "name.extension" from any kind of such uri.

Comment: Why not use that result and then just remove "attachment" then remove the last character ("?"). It seems like you stopped at the one yard line.

Comment: hint : subString method.

Comment: Oh damn I just realized that the uri above isn't the uri you were getting. Kindly edit your post and post the code so we can help you better.

Comment: @Razgriz I am looking for a general way to get the name.. there can be anything after ".png" in this case it is "?attachment".. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Writing this from the top of my head:

```
String filename = downloadingFile.getName().substring(0, downloadingFile.getName().length - 11);
```

Or to make it more readable

```
int filenameOriginalLength = downloadingFile.getName().length;
int excessStringLength = 11; // the string "?attachment" is 11 characters long

String filename = downloadingFile.getName().substring(0, filenameOriginalLength - excessStringLength);
```

Basically what we're doing here is that we're getting the substring of `downloadingFile.getName()` from the starting letter (index 0) until before the `?attachment` appears (length of your string - length of ?attachment).

Might be off by one character, you'd have to fine tune it by running it and adjusting `excessStringLength`.

Comment: I am looking for general solution where I can get the "name.extension" from any kind of such uri. I have edited my question.

Comment: Oh, then my answer should hold? Try it, it should give you `mushroom-967719_640.jpg`. :)